# How to construct API interface for retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

As mentioned in question, I need to construct an API interface for retrofit. This is my URL :

```
https://api.flightstats.com/flex/weather/rest/v1/json/all/COK?appId=XXXXXXXXX&appKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&codeType=IATA
//--------------------------------------------------------^^^--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As marked above, the problem lies at the position `COK`, which is an airport code, and I need to pass it in the request, however I am unable to pass it in my implementation of retrofit's interface creation. This is my code:

**WeatherApiClient.class**

```
    public class WeatherApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/weather/rest/v1/json/all/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**WeatherApiInterface.class**

```
 public interface WeatherApiInterface {
    @GET("COK") // this should be dynamic
    Call<WeatherPojo> getValues(@Query("appId") String appId, @Query("appKey") String key, @Query("codeType") String code);
}
```

How should I change my code so that I can pass the airport's code also while making a request?

Comment: I don't know well about retrofit but how about adding "COK" to getValues()? And you need query key for position. (It should be someKey=COK in query string.)

Comment: And maybe @Get(".") or like that.

Answer (score 1):

As your question you have already created Retrofit instance.

```
 public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/weather/rest/v1/json/all/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
```

You also mention in your code a Endpoint.This Encode detail about
the parameter and request method.

```
public interface WeatherApiInterface
   {    @GET("COK")
    //----^^^--
      Call<WeatherPojo> getValues(@Query("appId") String appId, @Query("appKey") String key, @Query("codeType") String code);
   }
```

**But missing part in your code it is your a async operation.** Put this code in your activity class.

```
ApiInterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(WeatherApiInterface.class);

        Call<WeatherPojo> call = apiService.getValues(appId,appKey,codeType);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherPojo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WeatherPojo>call, Response<WeatherPojo> response) {
                List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
                Log.d(TAG, "Number of movies received: " + movies.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WeatherPojo>call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `intreface` code,

```
public interface WeatherApiInterface{
    @GET("{id}")
    Call<WeatherPojo> getValues(@Path("id") String airportId, @Query("appId") String appId, @Query("appKey") String key, @Query("codeType") String code);
}
```

You haven't shown how you are invoking this. So I assume it is fine.

Comment: What is the error? Works like a charm for me. Should I add my whole code?